# Como otimizar a geração de combinações?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
const montar = (volante, todos, posicao, restantes) => {
  if (restantes === 0) {
    return [volante];
  }

  const tamanho = todos.length - (restantes - 1);
  let novos = [];

  for (let indice = posicao; indice < tamanho; indice++) {
    const possivel = todos[indice];
    const volantes = montar([...volante, possivel], todos, indice + 1, restantes - 1);
    novos = [...novos, ...volantes];
  }

  return novos;
};

console.time('Calculando');
console.log(montar([], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, 3).length);
console.timeEnd('Calculando');
```

Ele gera todos os volantes de loteria possíveis dados os números que podem ser escolhidos e a quantidade por volante. Porém, acredito que decido a recursão, a quantidade de memória alocada para calcular as possibilidades de jogos com muitos números possíveis torna a execução inviável.

Gostaria de **otimizar o uso de memória** deste código para conseguir gerar, por exemplo, todos os volantes da mega-sena (que são 6 números escolhidos dentre 1 à 60, gerando 50.063.860 `arrays`) **sem prejudicar o desempenho**.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é uma páginaçao e retornar N números por página

Comment: Já tentou calcular o quanto de bytes vai ocupar essas combinações? Você tem 50 milhões de vetores de 6 números; sem _overhead_ de arrays, você precisa alocar pelo menos o suficiente para 300 milhões de inteiros (6 * 50 milhões); hipoteticamente, se conseguirmos falar que só se necessita de 1 byte para esses inteiros, então são 300 milhões de bytes, 286 MiB. Agora, considerando um tamanho tradicional de 4 bytes, são 1.2 bilhões de bytes. pouco mais que 1 GiB. Isso sem considerar os _overheads_ de arrays...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado faz sentido, não tinha parado pra calcular!

Comment: Posso sugerir uma compactação da combinação. Um número que, através de um processo de descompactação, se torne a combinação adequada. Assim, você só precisaria enviar a função de descompactação e algo para indicar "tudo de 0 até 50.063.860"... interessa?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acredito que sim... a intenção é gerar todas as combinações no final mesmo